# Populating Google Maps using QGIS exported GeoJSON

Tags: qgis, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api

I am populating a Google map using GeoJSON that I'm exporting with QGIS.  I'm converting the TIGER shapefiles into GeoJSON for state polygons.  I used the standard output, and received the file.  My problem is Google Maps API is not accepting them.

Example output:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "REGION": "3", "DIVISION": "5", "STATEFP": "54", "STATENS": "01779805", "GEOID": "54", "STUSPS": "WV", "NAME": "West Virginia", "LSAD": "00", "MTFCC": "G4000", "FUNCSTAT": "A", "ALAND": 62266296765, "AWATER": 489206049, "INTPTLAT": "+38.6472854", "INTPTLON": "-080.6183274" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -81.7472545, 39.0953799 ], [ -81.7477735, 39.0947589 ],
```

When I import it into Google Maps:

```
function initialize() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 49.496675, lng: -102.65625 },
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson('data/states.json')
}
```

The error shows:

> not a Feature or FeatureCollection
>
> "Error
> at new be (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAn2PAcKggOaveyqEkBJCGTYyEUnNqz9Gk&v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize:97:207)
> at _.ee (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAn2PAcKggOaveyqEkBJCGTYyEUnNqz9Gk&v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize:98:87)
> at _.Jba (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAn2PAcKggOaveyqEkBJCGTYyEUnNqz9Gk&v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize:124:9)
> at jg.addGeoJson (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAn2PAcKggOaveyqEkBJCGTYyEUnNqz9Gk&v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize:312:48)
> at initialize (https://dev.offrs.com/evan/js/zipmap.js:6:12)
> at [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAn2PAcKggOaveyqEkBJCGTYyEUnNqz9Gk&v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize:240:146\](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAn2PAcKggOaveyqEkBJCGTYyEUnNqz9Gk&v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize:240:146%5C)
> at [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAn2PAcKggOaveyqEkBJCGTYyEUnNqz9Gk&v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize:239:237"](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAn2PAcKggOaveyqEkBJCGTYyEUnNqz9Gk&v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize:239:237%22)

Is there a format setting I need to be looking at to make the GeoJSON work properly?

Comment: I’m sorry I’m confused on what you’re trying to say

Comment: that is the file.  it is in the data folder under states.json.  What am I missing?

Comment: ohhh...wait.  that didn't work before...The reason why I think this is a partial QGIS issue, is becuase I downloaded other JSON before out of github, and used `map.data.loadGeoJson(
      "data/states.json"
  );`. and it worked without fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.
The JSON exceeded the size allotment for Google Maps.
When I broke down the JSON into smaller chunks, they just loaded perfectly.

Lessons learned. When exporting  layers from QGIS...check the JSON file size.  I think it needs to be <10Mb or something.

Of note, you CAN pass a path into the `loadGeoJson` call.

```
let counties = new google.maps.Data({map:map});
counties.loadGeoJson('data/counties/STATEFP_' + state + '.json');
```

Works like a champ.

Comment: If you consider this to be the solution, please accept your own answer (the tick icon to the left). It will help future readers with the same problem to quickly see a working solution has been provided.